# Can I use a custom matcher with sinon.assert.calledWith?

Tags: sinon

Sinon asserts are better when trying to check if a function was correctly called with arguments because it will tell you what part of the argument failed.

That said, I'm having trouble to get it to work with a custom matcher. The docs says that `sinon.assert.calledWithMatch` is the same as `sinon.assert.calledWith(spy, sinon.match(args))`, which led me to believe I could do

```
sinon.assert.calledWith(spy, sinon.match(args => args.foo = 'bar'))
```

But it seems that is not the case.

Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: 2021 now, but shouldn't `args.foo = 'bar'` use a double or triple equals?

Comment: @Jim damn, I don't recall what I was doing. Maybe that was the reason why it wasn't working, I don't know. Thanks for looking into this even years later.